# Add card elements from database on button click in Code Igniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter-3

Say I have a blank page and a button (somewhere in the top right corner), and a database in MySQL.

When I click that button I want to be able to create a square on the page (a contact card) with content from my database from MySQL.

And when I click it again I want to be able to create another card next to it with the same dimensions and so on (i.e every click adds a card till theres 4 in a row, then starts on the bottom of the card until the whole page is filled).

I am unsure on how I can accomplish this task. So, i need your help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic example from me

html:

```
<button class="add">
add
</button>
<div class="main">

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery :

```
var card = '<div><p><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bd8oIcSCAAAqTaZ.jpg" style="width:60px; height:60px; margin-right:10px">Hello</p></div>';
var hit=0;
$('.add').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
hit = hit + 1;
$('.main').prepend(card+' '+hit);
/*$.ajax({url:yourUrl,data:yourData,type:'post',
success:function(data){ // With ajax you can pass hit to your data to get different result
 $('.main').prepend(data);
 }
 });*/
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4qyzLbc/)

Maybe it can help you

Comment: While this will surely help to solve OP's request, it's not a good idea to provide spoon-fed answers.